# Move Python Dictionary From A Dictionary to Another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, move

I am making a game in Python and am storing dictionaries in lists as items:

```
equipped = {}

swords = {
        'wooden_sword': {'name': 'Wooden Sword', 'dmg': 1}
}
```

How would I move the `wooden_sword` item into the `equipped` lists.

(If i am not using correct terminology feel free to edit)

Comment: Those are dicts, not lists

Comment: I don't recommend doing this, it is considered a dict move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "equipped" is a dictionary (signified by the fact you used curly brackets) you would do it like this:

```
equipped.update({'wooden_sword':swords['wooden_sword']})
del swords['wooden_sword']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the value (actually, a copy of the value) at key `'wooden_sword'` in `equipped` dict to value from `swords` dict, then delete the value from `swords`:

```
...

equipped['wooden_sword'] = swords['wooden_sword'].copy()

del swords['wooden_sword']

print(swords)
print(equipped)
```

Output:

```
{}
{'wooden_sword': {'name': 'Wooden Sword', 'dmg': 1}}
```

If these dictionaries you're moving have more values other than int/str/float (other values such as lists/dicts/...), then consider using `deepcopy` to copy those inner values as well:

```
...
from copy import deepcopy

equipped['wooden_sword'] = deepcopy(swords['wooden_sword'])
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use something like:

```
equipped['wooden_sword'] = swords['wooden_sword'].copy()
```

I'd recommend to put another attribute to the sword instead of moving it, like this:

```
swords = {
        'wooden_sword': {
            'name': 'Wooden Sword',
            'dmg': 1,
            'equipped': True
        }
}
```

Like this you can just change an attribute inside 1 dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest use a class to keep an instance of the character's items. Then add whatever things you want, like swords, as attributes for that class like so:

```
class Equipment:
    def __init__(self):
        self.swords = {}

    def add_sword(self, sword):
        self.swords.update(sword)
```

Then you can have something like:

```
equipment = Equipment()

sword = {
    'wooden_sword': {'name': 'Wooden Sword', 'dmg': 1}
}

equipment.add_sword(sword)
```

Of course, you can also turn that sword dictionary into another class for a sword (which again, I recommend).
Hope that helps and good luck with your game!